# installing MySQLdb on mac

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have MAMP already installed in my mac.
So the mysql in MAMP is running just fine.
But when i try to install mysqldb , I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
metadata, options = get_config()
File "/Users/mohitdeepsingh/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 43, in    get_config
   libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
File "/Users/mohitdeepsingh/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 24, in     mysql_config
 raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

How should I troubleshoot this.
Most of the recommendations are to install mysql etc
but isnt mysql already there.
Do I need to change some sort of config file?If so can anyone point which config file I should be modifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to figure out, if there is a `mysql_config` binary in the MAMP, and if it is there, then to do:

`export PATH="path-to-the-dir-with-mysql-config:$PATH"`

before installing MySQL-python.

Comment: Hi.. I think the mysql config file is in export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config:$PATH"
 but still i get the same error

Comment: You have to do `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"` without `mysql_config` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Building MySQLdb on mac requires header files and dynamic libraries for MySQL, which are not included by standard MAMP. If you insist on using MAMP purely you can [read this guide](http://dreamconception.com/tech/how-to-install-mysqldb-mysql-python-on-mamp/).

**Fortunately**, there's a simpler solution: installing py27-mysql and then using mysql's headers and libs. Here's how it worked for me:

```
$ sudo port install py27-mysql

$ sudo env "PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin" pip install mysql-python
```